# Find the number of seven-letter words that use letters from a four-letter set and in which exactly three different letters appear.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There isn't specified set for the 4-letters, but I would assume it is from the set {A,B,...,Z} (but the text doesn't really say).

I have to use the T-(m,m) triangle and I originally thought the answer was T(7,3), but that is if we choose exactly 3 letters from the set of 4-letters.

Anyway, I'm very confused at what the question is ask. I'm hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: No that would be if you chose 3 letters out of 7

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 different "letter sets" that a looked for word could use: we omit one of the letters of the original 4 letter set.
For each of these letter sets we need to find all words of length 7 that use all 3 of them: this is $3^7$ - the number of words that only use 2 letters or 1 letter among them (mind the double counting). This amounts to $3^7 - 3\cdot 2^7 + 3$.
So I get in total $4(3^7 - 3\cdot 2^7 + 3)=7224$ as the answer. Confirmed by a small Python script.

If (as asked in the comments) we want exactly two different letters, we have $ {4\choose 2} = 6$ ways to choose the letter set out of the original 4, and after that $2^7 -2$ many good words (all words from 2 letters are $2^7$ but the two one-letter words have to subtracted, so in that case we have $6(2^7 - 2)=756$ words. Python agrees with me..

Comment: Would this reasoning work if exactly 2 different letters appears as well?

Comment: @Nixie777 see edit.